# MySQL MIN/MAX all row

Tags: mysql, select, max, min

I have table `Races` with the rows `ID`, `Name` and `TotalCP` . I SELECT MIN( `TotalCP` ) FROM `Races`, but then I want to select the entire row which have the minimum value. How I can make that, in a single query ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The general form for getting a whole row from an aggregated value is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Races
WHERE TotalCP = (SELECT MIN(TotalCP) FROM Races)
```

or

```
SELECT r.*
FROM
(
    SELECT MIN(TotalCP) t
    FROM Races
) m
INNER JOIN Races r ON m.t = r.TotalCP
```

However, in this case, since you're using `MIN`, you can just sort and take the first row:

```
SELECT *
FROM Races
ORDER BY TotalCP
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Is there any performance benefit/disadvantage of using the `ORDER BY col LIMIT 1` solution over the subquery? My understanding suggests not, as the storage engine has to read an end of the index in both cases to get the MIN/MAX value before checking the actual table data using a const ref to obtain the other column values... (assuming no covering index exists). But then again, the first solution is 2 queries, as opposed to the single query, so is there some overhead there?

Comment: @Jon I honestly not 100% sure, but I could definitely see how the first query could have to hit the index twice - once to retrieve the minimum value of `TotalCP`, then once again for the join. If `TotalCP` is unique *and* the optimizer knows this and was written specifically against this case it might not have to make the second lookup though. In either case though, worrying about something as small as this feels a bit like a premature micro-optimization IMHO. It's also worth pointing out that if `TotalCP` is not unique, the first query will return all rows whereas the latter only returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from Races
where TotalCP = SELECT MIN( TotalCP ) FROM Races
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery is your bet,

```
      SELECT * FROM Races where TotalCP = (SELECT MIN( TotalCP ) FROM Races)
```