# How to get max value and its row at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In 'album_head' table 'album_head_picture_id' is auto incremented primary key. I am trying to get the max of 'album_head_picture_id' and the entire row against that id. What is the sql? I tried this...

```
<?PHP  $maximim_id=$this->db->query('SELECT MAX(album_head_picture_id) AS 'maxid' FROM album_head')->row()->maxid;?>
```

and with that id, again...

```
<?PHP  $query = $this->db->query("
       SELECT * FROM album_head where album_head_picture_id= '.$maximim_id.'");

       return $query->result();
?>
```

i am trying to do that in same sql. Any Idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM album_head ORDER BY album_head_picture_id DESC LIMIT 1 ;`

Comment: @ypercube. Why would you put that in a comment? That looks like a perfectly good answer.

Comment: @FilipeSilva I was looking for a duplicate question so I can vote to close. This has been asked thousands of times.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL MIN/MAX all row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293778/mysql-min-max-all-row)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM album_head where album_head_picture_id=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table)
```